# For-loop with parameter Collection<?>

Tags: java

I have a method `public static void writeLines(Collection<?> lines, String path)`

And I want to iterate parameter `lines` like this: `for(? line : lines)`, but of course, there is an error at `?`.

How I can iterate parameter `lines`? Or what is generic type of `Collection`, to make it possible to iterate in `for-loop`?

Comment: The common type is `Object`!

Comment: Use `Object` instead of `?`

Comment: [How to iterate over a wildcard generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6271960)

Comment: You have to say `for (Object line: lines)`

Comment: I forgot about `Object`, my bad. I'm not very familiar with generics. Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you change your method signature to `public static <T> void writeLines(Collection<T> lines, String path)`?

Comment: @MauricePerry I can, but there would be a difference compared with `Object`?

Comment: @KunLun yes: you would do `for(T line: lines)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to:

```
for (Object line : lines){
   //Your code
}
```

Or if you are using Java8+ you don't care about the type, you can just use:

```
lines.forEach(line -> /*Your code*/)
```

Comment: I know about `forEach`, but I need clasic `for` to throw exceptions. I also forgot about `Object`. I'm not very familiar with generics. Really thanks.